# Insert database row via ASP.net 4.5 GridView on-board functionality?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, insert, sqldatasource

I would like to insert a database entry by using standard functions of my GridView and SqlDataSource. Has there been any update on this topic since the dirty workarounds some versions ago (e.g. see [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24085/Insert-Update-Delete-with-Gridview-Simple-Way), [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12657/GridView-inline-Master-Detail-record-display))? I could not find any new tutorials on the web.

For example, is there any handler that allows the entry to be written to the database by using the standard -Datafield and the UpdateCommand of the SqlDataSource? At the moment, the UpdateCommand does not seem to get my entered value.
How can I debug those SqlDataSource-Database-Queries properly?

Heres the solution I've tried to get it working with: My database table tblname contains only one column, "name".

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:VConStr %>"
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [tblname] WHERE [name] = @name" 
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [tblname] ([name]) VALUES (@name)" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [name] FROM [tblname]"
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [tblname] SET [name] = @name WHERE [name] = @name">
    <DeleteParameters><asp:Parameter Name="name" Type="String" /></DeleteParameters>
    <InsertParameters><asp:Parameter Name="name" Type="String" /></InsertParameters>
    <UpdateParameters><asp:Parameter Name="name" Type="String" /></UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="name" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ShowFooter="true">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" ShowHeader="True">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("name") %>' />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="Insertname" name="name_new" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("name") %>' />
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" ShowHeader="True">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit" />
                <asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Sure?');" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Edit entry" CommandName="Update" />
                <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="Button5" runat="server" Text="New" CommandName="Insert" />
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: may this helps http://satindersinght.blogspot.in/2012/08/how-to-addupdate-record-using-gridview.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this solution does in fact require to manually insert the entry into the database in the coding. I'd like to avoid this and user on-board functions for this. Select/Update/Delete-operations also work without establishing a custom connection to the database.